# ¿Saben solucionar error en Laravel: Trying to get property 'status' of non-object?

Tags: php, laravel

Hola estimados señores,

Necesito resolver este problema de un sccript sencillo que funciona en Laravel, tengo nulo conocimiento en códigos.

El script me iba perfectamente hasta que de pronto, sin haber tocado nada de código, al subir imágenes en modo usuario para crear algo de contenido, me apareció el error que detallo a continuación:

```
ErrorException
Creating default object from empty value (View:/public_html/resources/views/index.blade.php) 

Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError
resources/views/index.blade.php:8
```

Incluyo el Archivo index.blade.php del cual parece que salta el error:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<!-- latest Items Section -->
<div class="row row-cards">
    @forelse($items as $item)
    
    @if(!empty($setting ?? ''::find('adv_top')->value))
    @if($adv_top->status == 1)
    @if($loop->first)
    <div class="col-3">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body text-center">
                <p>{!! $adv_top->value !!}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endif
    @endif
    @endif
    
    @if(!empty($setting ?? ''::find('adv_bottom')->value))
    @if($adv_bottom->status == 1)
    @if($loop->last)
    <div class="col-3">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body text-center">
                <p>{!! $adv_bottom->value !!}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endif
    @endif
    @endif
    
    @include('layouts.item')
    @empty
    @include('layouts.blank')
    @endforelse
    {{ $items->links() }}
</div>
@endsection('content')
```

A continuación os incluyo el controlador que me indica el error:

HomeController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File; 
use Image;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Models\Settings;
use App\Models\Pages;
use App\Models\Items;
use App\Models\Images;
use App\Models\Likes;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Categories;
use App\Models\ItemsViews;
use App\Models\Notifications;
use App\Models\Reports;
use App\Models\Follow;
use \Conner\Tagging\Taggable;
use Overtrue\LaravelLike\Traits\Likeable;
use App\Models\Advertising;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    
    use Likeable;
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->categories = Categories::where('status', 1)->get();
        $this->pages = Pages::where('status', 1)->get();
        $this->most_used_tags = \Conner\Tagging\Model\Tag::where('count', '>=', 2)->limit('3')->get();
        $this->results_per_page = Settings::find('results_per_page')->value;
        $this->itemsRandomOrder = Items::inRandomOrder()->take(Settings::find('random_items')->value)->get();
        $this->usersRandomOrder = User::inRandomOrder()->take(Settings::find('random_users')->value)->get();
        $this->setting = Settings::first();
    }
    
    /**
     * Index
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {

        // get items list
        $items = Items::whereHas('category', function ($query) {
            $query->where('status', 1); // only where the category it belongs to is active
        })->whereHas('user', function ($query) {
            $query->where('access', 1); // only by users with a public profile
        })->where('visible', 1)
            ->where('status', 1)
            ->orderByDesc('id')
            ->paginate($this->results_per_page);

        return view('index')->with([
            'site_name' => Settings::find('site_name')->value,
            'site_description' => Settings::find('site_description')->value,
            'page_name' => Settings::find('site_tagline')->value,
            'items' => $items,
            'categories' => $this->categories,
            'pages' => $this->pages,
            'setting' => $this->setting,
            'adv_top' => Advertising::where('id', Settings::find('adv_top')->value)->first(),
            'adv_bottom' => Advertising::where('id', Settings::find('adv_bottom')->value)->first(),
        ]);
        
    }
    
    /**
     * Hot
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function hot()
    {
        
        // get hot items
        $items = Items::withCount('hot')
            ->whereHas('category', function ($query) {
                $query->where('status', 1);
            })->whereHas('user', function ($query) {
                $query->where('access', 1);
            })->where('visible', 1)
              ->where('status', 1)
              ->orderByDesc('hot_count')
              ->paginate($this->results_per_page);
        
        return view('index')->with([
            'site_name' => Settings::find('site_name')->value,
            'site_description' => Settings::find('site_description')->value,
            'page_name' => __('main.hot'),
            'items' => $items,
            'categories' => $this->categories,
            'pages' => $this->pages,
            //'tags' => $this->most_used_tags
        ]);
        
    }
    
    /**
     * Most Liked
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function most_liked()
    {
        
        // get most Liked items
        $items = Items::withCount('most_liked')
            ->whereHas('category', function ($query) {
                $query->where('status', 1);
            })->whereHas('user', function ($query) {
                $query->where('access', 1);
            })->where('visible', 1)
              ->where('status', 1)
              ->orderByDesc('most_liked_count')
              ->paginate($this->results_per_page);
        
        return view('index')->with([
            'site_name' => Settings::find('site_name')->value,
            'site_description' => Settings::find('site_description')->value,
            'page_name' => __('main.most_liked'),
            'items' => $items,
            'categories' => $this->categories,
            'pages' => $this->pages,
            //'tags' => $this->most_used_tags
        ]);
        
    }
    
    /**
     * Most Commented
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function most_commented()
    {
        
        // get most Commented items
        $items = Items::withCount('most_commented')
            ->whereHas('category', function ($query) {
                $query->where('status', 1);
            })->whereHas('user', function ($query) {
                $query->where('access', 1);
            })->where('visible', 1)
              ->where('status', 1)
              ->orderByDesc('most_commented_count')
              ->paginate($this->results_per_page);
        
        return view('index')->with([
            'site_name' => Settings::find('site_name')->value,
            'site_description' => Settings::find('site_description')->value,
            'page_name' => __('main.most_commented'),
            'items' => $items,
            'categories' => $this->categories,
            'pages' => $this->pages,
            //'tags' => $this->most_used_tags
        ]);
        
    }
    
    /**
     * Featured
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function featured()
    {
        // get featured items list
        $items = Items::whereHas('category', function ($query) {
            $query->where('status', 1); 
        })->whereHas('user', function ($query) {
            $query->where('access', 1); // only by users with a public profile
        })->where('visible', 1)
            ->where('status', 1)
            ->where('featured', 1)
            ->orderByDesc('id')
            ->paginate($this->results_per_page);

        return view('index')->with([
            'site_name' => Settings::find('site_name')->value,
            'site_description' => Settings::find('site_description')->value,
            'page_name' => __('main.featured'),
            'items' => $items,
            'categories' => $this->categories,
            'pages' => $this->pages,
            //'tags' => $this->most_used_tags
        ]);
        
    }
    
    /**
     * Following
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function following()
    {

        $items = Items::whereIn('user_id', function($query) {
            $query->select('following_id')
                ->from('user_follower')
                ->where('follower_id', Auth::id());
        })->whereHas('category', function ($query) {
            $query->where('status', 1); // only where the category it belongs to is active
        })->whereHas('user', function ($query) {
            $query->where('access', 1); // only by users with a public profile
        })->where('visible', 1)
            ->where('status', 1)
            ->orderByDesc('id')
            ->paginate($this->results_per_page);
        
        return view('following')->with([
            'site_name' => Settings::find('site_name')->value,
            'site_description' => Settings::find('site_description')->value,
            'page_name' => __('main.following'),
            'items' => $items,
            'categories' => $this->categories,
            'pages' => $this->pages,
            'randomUsers' => $this->usersRandomOrder
        ]);
    }
    
    /**
     * Upload New Post
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function upload()
    {
        return view('upload')->with([
            'site_name' => Settings::find('site_name')->value,
            'site_description' => Settings::find('site_description')->value,
            'page_name' => __('main.upload'),
            'categories' => $this->categories,
            'pages' => $this->pages
        ]);
    }
    
    /**
     * Store New Post
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store_image(Request $request)
    {
        
        if(Settings::find('active_upload')->value == 0){
            toastr()->warning(__('main.new_entries_paused'));
            return redirect('/');
        }
        
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'description' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'tags' => 'nullable',
            'category_id' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required',
            'image.*' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:'.Settings::find('max_filesize')->value
        ]);
        
        if($request->has('visible')){ $visible = 2; } else { $visible = 1; }
        if($request->has('active_comments')){ $active_comments = 2; } else { $active_comments = 1; }
        if($request->has('active_views')){ $active_views = 2; } else { $active_views = 1; }
        if($request->has('active_likes')){ $active_likes = 2; } else { $active_likes = 1; }
        
        //** create item
        $create_item = Items::create([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'slug' => Str::slug(request('title'), '-'),
            'visible' => $visible,
            'status' => Settings::find('new_entries')->value,
            'active_comments' => $active_comments,
            'active_views' => $active_views,
            'active_likes' => $active_likes,
            'user_id' => Auth::id(),
            'category_id' => $request->category_id
        ]);
        
        if($create_item == true){
            //** create tags
            $tags = explode(",", $request->tags);
            $create_item->tag($tags);
            
            // ** add image
            if($request->hasfile('image')){
                
                foreach($request->file('image') as $image){
                    //$image = $request->file('image');
                    $input['imagename'] = Str::random(24).'.'.$image->extension();
                    $destinationPath = 'storage/app/public/images/thumbnail';

                    $img = Image::make($image->path());
                    $img->resize(450, 300, function ($constraint) {
                        $constraint->aspectRatio();
                    })->save($destinationPath.'/'.$input['imagename']);

                    $destinationPath = 'storage/app/public/images';
                    $image->move($destinationPath, $input['imagename']);
                    //$img = Image::make($image->path())->fit(300, 160)->save($destinationPath.'/'.$input['imagename']);
                    
                    $create_image[] = Images::create([
                        'item_id' => $create_item->id,
                        'file_name' => $input['imagename']
                    ]);
                }
            }
            
            if(Settings::find('new_entries')->value == 1){
            
                toastr()->success(__('main.toast_your_post_has_been_posted'));
                return redirect('/');
                
            } else {
                
                toastr()->warning(__('main.toast_post_in_moderation'));
                return redirect('/');
                
            }
            
            
        } else {
            toastr()->error(__('main.toast_there_are_problems_try_again'));
            return redirect('/');
        }
        
    }
    
    /**
     * Show Item
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id, $slug)
    {
        
        $item = Items::whereHas('category', function ($query) {
                $query->where('status', 1); 
            })->whereHas('user', function ($query) {
                $query->where('access', 1); // only by users with a public profile
            })->where('id', $id)
                ->where('slug', $slug)
                ->where('status', 1)
                ->firstOrFail();
        
        ItemsViews::createViewLog($item);
        
        return view('layouts.item.show')->with([
            'site_name' => Settings::find('site_name')->value,
            'site_description' => Settings::find('site_description')->value,
            'page_name' => Str::limit($item->title, 30),
            'categories' => $this->categories,
            'pages' => $this->pages,
            'item' => $item,
            'randomItems' => $this->itemsRandomOrder,
            'randomUsers' => $this->usersRandomOrder
        ]);
    }
    
    /**
     * Edit Item
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit_post($id, $slug)
    {
            
        $item = Items::where('id', $id)
            ->where('slug', $slug)
            ->where('status', 1)
            ->firstOrFail();
        
        // validation if this post does not belong to the logged in user
        if($item->user_id !== Auth::id()){
            toastr()->info(__("Questo non è il tuo post"));
            return redirect('/');
        }
        
        return view('layouts.item.edit')->with([
            'site_name' => Settings::find('site_name')->value,
            'site_description' => Settings::find('site_description')->value,
            'page_name' => __('main.edit_post'),
            'categories' => $this->categories,
            'pages' => $this->pages,
            'item' => $item
        ]);
        
    }
    
    /**
     * Store Edit Post
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit_post_store(Request $request)
    {
        
        if($request->has('visible')){ $visible = 2; } else { $visible = 1; }
        if($request->has('active_comments')){ $active_comments = 2; } else { $active_comments = 1; }
        if($request->has('active_views')){ $active_views = 2; } else { $active_views = 1; }
        if($request->has('active_likes')){ $active_likes = 2; } else { $active_likes = 1; }
        
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'description' => 'required|string|max:255',
        ]);
        
        $item = Items::where('id', $request->item_id)
            ->where('status', 1)
            ->firstOrFail();
        
        $item->title = $request->title;
        $item->description = $request->description;
        $item->slug = Str::slug($request->title, '-');
        $item->visible = $visible;
        $item->active_comments = $active_comments;
        $item->active_views = $active_views;
        $item->active_likes = $active_likes;
        
        if($item->save() == true){
            toastr()->success(__('main.toast_post_updated_successfully'));
            return redirect('/');
        } else {
            toastr()->error(__('main.toast_there_are_problems_try_again'));
            return back();
        }
        
    }
    
    /**
     * Delete Item By User
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function delete_user_post($id){
        
        $item = Items::where('id', $id)
            ->firstOrFail();
        
        if(Auth::id() !== $item->user_id){
            toastr()->error(__("It is not your post."));
            return back();
        }
 
        //
        foreach($item->all_images_carousel() as $image){
            if(is_file('storage/app/public/images/'.$image->file_name)){
                $delete_image = File::delete('storage/app/public/images/'.$image->file_name);
            }

            if(is_file('storage/app/public/images/thumbnail/'.$image->file_name)){
                $delete_thumb = File::delete('storage/app/public/images/thumbnail/'.$image->file_name);
            }
            
            //
            foreach($item->tags as $tag) {
                $item->untag();
            }
        }
           
        $query = Items::find($item->id);
        
        if($query->delete() == true){
            toastr()->success(__('main.toast_post_deleted'));
            return redirect('/');
        } else {
            toastr()->error(__('main.toast_there_are_problems_try_again'));
            return redirect('/');
        }
        
    }
    
    /**
     * Search
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        
        $request->validate([
            'key' => 'required',
        ]);

        // get items list
        if($request->has('key')) {
            
            $items = Items::whereHas('category', function ($query) {
                $query->where('status', 1); 
            })->whereHas('user', function ($query) {
                $query->where('access', 1); // only by users with a public profile
            })->search($request->key)->where('visible', 1)->where('status', 1)->orderByDesc('id')->paginate($this->results_per_page);
            
        }

        return view('search')->with([
            'site_name' => Settings::find('site_name')->value,
            'site_description' => Settings::find('site_description')->value,
            'page_name' => $request->key,
            'items' => $items,
            'categories' => $this->categories,
            'pages' => $this->pages
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Users Page
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function users(Request $request)
    {

        // get users list
        if($request->has('key')) {
            
            $request->validate([
                'key' => 'required',
            ]);
            
            $users = User::when($request->key, function ($query, $key) {
                return $query->where('name', 'like', "%{$key}%");
                })->where('access', 1)->orderByDesc('id')->paginate($this->results_per_page);
            
        } else {
            
            $users = User::where('access', 1)
            ->orderByDesc('id')
            ->paginate($this->results_per_page);
            
        }

        return view('users')->with([
            'site_name' => Settings::find('site_name')->value,
            'site_description' => Settings::find('site_description')->value,
            'page_name' => __('main.users').' ('.$users->currentPage().')',
            'users' => $users,
            'categories' => $this->categories,
            'pages' => $this->pages
        ]);
    }
    
    /**
     * Like System
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    function save_like(Request $request){
        
        $item = Items::findOrFail($request->item);
        
        if(Auth::user()->hasLiked($item)) {
            
            Auth::user()->unlike($item);
            
            return response()->json([
                'bool'=>false
            ]);

        } else {
            
            $like = Auth::user()->like($item);
            
            Notifications::create([
                'sender_id' => Auth::id(),
                'recipient_id' => $item->user_id,
                'item_id' => $item->id,
                'notification_type' => "like",
                'like_id' => Auth::user()->likes()->with('likeable')->first()->id,
                'seen' => 2,
            ]);
            
            return response()->json([
                'bool' => true
            ]);
            
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Favorite System
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    function save_favorite(Request $request){
        
        $item = Items::findOrFail($request->item);
        
        if($request->user()->hasFavorited($item)) {
            
            $request->user()->unfavorite($item);
            
            return response()->json([
                'bool'=>false
            ]);

        } else {
            
            $request->user()->favorite($item);
            
            return response()->json([
                'bool'=>true
            ]);
        }
        
    }
    
    /**
     * Toogle Follow/Unfollow
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function toggle_follow(Request $request){
        
        $user = User::findOrFail($request->input('user_id'));
        
        if($request->user()->isFollowing($user)){
            
            $request->user()->unfollow($user);
            return response()->json([
                'bool'=>false
            ]);
            
        } else {
            
            $request->user()->follow($user);
            return response()->json([
                'bool'=>true
            ]);
            
        }
 
    }
    
    /**
     * Report
     * @id
     *
     */
    public function report($id)
    {
        
        $report = Reports::create([
            'user_id' => Auth::id(),
            'item_id' => $id,
        ]);
        
        if($report == true){
            toastr()->warning(__('main.toast_your_report_has_been_sent'));
            return redirect('/');
        } else {
            toastr()->error(__('main.toast_there_are_problems_try_again'));
            return back();
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo y ayuda, lo aprecio mucho. Saludos

Comment: esta parte `?? ''::find('adv_top')->value)` en concreto las dos comillas con la llamada estática (los dos puntos) tiene pinta de ser el error no creo que un string tenga un método find, parece que se elimino la entidad por un string vacío. Aún que no se a que entidad se llamaría.

Comment: Hola @Xerif, ante todo gracias por su respuesta y su ayuda. Entonces usted quiere decir que algo ahí de las 2 comillas o puntos habría que cambiar y que falta alguna identidad que hay que añadir o algo así? realmente no entiendo de código y lo que me dice me suena a chino. :O

Comment: Si por ahí parece que va el error. Me aventuró a decir que quieren buscar que si no le llega setting busque en la base de datos. Puedes probar cambiando esas comillas por `\App\Models\Settings` quedando algo como `\App\Models\Settings::::find('adv_top')->value` pero no te puedo decir más  sin entrar en materia de dominio